# How to push array with key?

Tags: php

I want do like this:

```
$m_array = array();

foreach ($values as $key) { <- $key is just string
    array_push ( $m_array, $key => array() );
}

/////result
$m_array = array(
    "key1" => array(),
    "key2" => array(),
    ....
);
```

How to do this?

Please help me.

I use PHP.

Comment: whats in the $values aray? this question is not clear

Comment: Im sorry.
$value is just array.
the $key is "apple", "melon", "banana".... like this each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `array_push` to append to arrays. `array_push` is the same as `$array[] = $val`.

In your case you want to specify keys:

```
$m_array = array();

foreach ($values as $key) { <- $key is just string
    $m_array[$key] = array();
}
```

Note that `array_push` does have a use if you want to push more than one value at once because you can do something like this:

```
array_push($array, $value1, $value2, $value3)
```

Comment: $key here is not the array key; which may or may not be an issue

Comment: Yes, `$key` here refers to a value of `$values` which will be a key in the new array - Not confusing at all! /s